# How to create the spacing between tableview sections? ( Header and Footer of every section are already custom views)

Tags: swift, tableview

I want to implement a table with:

- sections
- every section will have footer and header
- footer and header will be sticky to the table
- between every section there is a space

It will look like this:

[image]

I don't know **how to implement the space between sections.**

a) the usual method for this is setting the height of section header or section footer.

b) I have tried out to make the footer contain the space between sections, but then the sticky footer also contained this space, which looks ugly:

[image]

This is how I have configured headers and footers of every section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let contentView = UIView()
    ......
    return contentView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let contentView = UIView()
    ......
    return contentView
}
```

I need custom headers and footers, because I want to use the sticky feature of those, meaning on top of the table will be shown the current header section and on the bottom the last visible section footer (so those change with the scroll).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell there is no "easy" way of doing what you want. But it's not that hard either. As @Tom suggested you need to use an empty cell for your empty spaces. But the empty cell has to be put in it's own section that has no header or footer.

I put together something really quick to to get you started (add this to a Playground to see it in action). In the image bellow headers are green, content cells are blue, footers yellow and the spacers white:

[image]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ContentCell: UITableViewCell {

}

class SectionSpacerCell: UITableViewCell {

}

class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableView: UITableView!

    private var sections: [Int] = []

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds)
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        tableView.register(ContentCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell")
        tableView.register(SectionSpacerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SectionSpacerCell")

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sections = [4, 7, 4, 2, 7]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count > 0 ? sections.count + (sections.count - 1) : 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section % 2 == 0 ? sections[section / 2] : 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section % 2 == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContentCell") as? ContentCell else {
                fatalError("Oops!")
            }
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue
            return cell
        }
        else {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionSpacerCell") as? SectionSpacerCell else {
                fatalError("Oops!")
            }
            cell.backgroundColor = .white
            return cell
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section % 2 == 0 {
            return 40
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section % 2 == 0 {
            let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
            headerView.backgroundColor = .green
            return headerView
        }
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section % 2 == 0 {
            return 40
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section % 2 == 0 {
            let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
            headerView.backgroundColor = .yellow
            return headerView
        }
        return nil
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: This is quite clean. I'll try it out and approve it.

Comment: It is working. Thanks. I can only award bounty in 17 hours.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `heightForFooterInSection UITableViewDelegate` function:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614967-tableview

You can vary the size between sections; so for the last section, return 0 (or whatever makes sense)

Comment: header and footer of the section are customised in a delegate like `tableView(tableView:viewForFooterInSection:section:)`. The heightForFooterInSection returns exactly as many points are needed for the footer. Header and footer are sticky.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an "empty space" table view row for every section except the last section?

Comment: Maybe if I would have shown some code, the question would have been more to the point. The table has sections, where every section has header and footer - `func tableView(_: viewForHeaderInSection:) -> UIView?` `func tableView(_: viewForFooterInSection:) -> UIView?`,`func tableView(tableView: heightForHeaderInSection:) -> CGFloat`,  `func tableView(tableView: heightForFooterInSection:)`.

Comment: So, I have configured everything for the headers and footers of the section. I don't want to make those artificial using simple cells in `cellForRowAt:`, because I need the sticky feature - on top and bottom of the table ( as much that is visible on the screen), there will be always a header and a footer sown.